# Unable to deploy asp.net mvc project on the IIS server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have created a folder (main)  inside the following directory  C:\inetpub\wwwroot\

I have also published the project from Visual Studio to the above directory/

On clicking Browse from IIS,I get the following message

**Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 10.216.19.153:56223.**

Comment: That port seems more that you are running using a visual studio dev server.  If you're sure it's when you run through IIS, check what port you running (in IIS, click on website, bindings, and it'll show the port).   As 56223 isn't normal unless you've explicitly set that.

Comment: Site Bindings shows Port 56223. I haven't explicitly set it.

Answer (score 0):

Default WebSite in IIS which is stored in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\` folder has address `localhost:80`

If you want to add a new website or a Virtual Directory in default website (for example `localhost\myVirtualDir`) you have to do it in `IIS Manager`

Comment: I have done the same using IIS manager. First I create a folder in the wwwroot directory.Then I published my Project to that directory  by right clicking on my project and clicking on Publish. After that when I clicked on browse through the IIS manager I got the error - 

Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 10.216.19.153:56223.